# Need to roll the database back to previous state

Tags: android, rollback, ormlite, autocommit

Here is my model classes that are persisted in sqlite db using ORMLITE.

```
public class Site{
                 ...
                 ...
                 Collection<Visit> visits;
                 }

public class Visit{
                 ...
                 ...
                 Collection<Pic> pics;
                 }

public class Pic{
                 ...
                 ...

                 }
```

Now in one view i add,edit or delete from these three tables. There is a button in my view to cancel the changes(add,edit,delete). So i need to rollback to previous state of the db.

How can i achieve this roll back to a certain state of the three tables using ormlite with android?

I have read in ormlite docs about **DAO.SetAutoCommit()** and **startThreadConnection()** methods. I think i can do it by using this two. But cant figure it out how to use them. Please suggest me how to do it.

Here is my DBHelper Class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
// name of the database file 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Test.db";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private Dao<Site, Integer> siteListDao = null;
private Dao<Visit, Integer> visitDao= null;
private Dao<Pic,Integer> picDao=null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database,ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Site.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Visit.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Pic.class);
                 } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    public Dao<Visit, Integer> getVisitDao() {
    if (null == visitDao) {
        try {
            visitDao = getDao(Visit.class);
        }catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return visitDao;
}
    .....
     .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I mostly agree with @Stefan.  I think you need to do this inside of your application and not rely on a database construct to all you to return to a previous state.

Turning off auto-commit (which [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) uses transactions under Sqlite) or using transactions directly is *not* how to do this.  Transactions are designed to allow you to make multiple changes to the database and then roll them all back if one database change fails.  They are not intended to stay open for seconds waiting for user input.

- You could have a committed boolean field or some such in your data to make it easier to "revert" the database by deleting all objects where the `committed = false` or some such.
- You could have separate tables so objects are stored to a session table and then copied over to the main tables when the user commits their work.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick suggession. I will consider your two options. I am doing a clone of IOS app to android so the design flow changing is not a option for me.

Comment: But as i am curious to know if i do it with auto commit off and do the rollback before commit(keeping connection open) what may be the problem?

Comment: Maybe nothing.  Just remember that there is a single connection open to the database.  Any other database operations will be affected by holding the connection in a transaction like that @rawcoder064.

Comment: If i ensure that any other database operations of my application will not be executed during that period is that be any problem then?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm don't know about any methods that will do this for you automatically. If you really wanna do it automatically, you could also check out Transactions. They have build-in controls to roll-back on fail. Not exactly what you want, but maybe adjustable.

You could also just do it more manually and save 1 (last) object in memory, the object you're going to delete. If a person wants to 'undo' the change, you can just re-add that object with ORMLite. Probably a lot easier than other options.

Comment: I can see DAO.rollBack(DatabaseConnection connection) method. But wonder whether its usefull or not.

Comment: About your second suggession.....as you can see from my data structure there can be many pics in one visit and many more visit in one site....so storing this many data in memory is not helpful....is it?

Comment: In memory might not be correct, but the point is that the library is called 'ormLITE'. It provides you with the basic needs for an ORM without getting to heavy for a mobile device. You'll have to manually handle rolling back your database. There are numerous options to do this such as constantly building a custom roll-back query, keeping the objects in memory or adjusting your database structure as @Gray advises with a temp table or field. Point is, you'll have to do it yourself in the best way you can that fits into your logic. Ps it's Gray's library, so take his advise to heart ;)